# Currency not correctly converting when using currency switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, ce-1.9.2.0

I am following below reference to use *currency dropdown* in my project.

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Currently in my site both `default` and `base` currency is set to **Indian Rupee** .

Let's say there is a product of `₹60`, if I change currency to `USD` using switcher, `price` should be showing `$0.90`, instead it is showing as `₹3976.20` which is multiplied with currency rate.

Any hints?

I am using Magento 1.9.2

**Screenshots1:**

[image]

**Screenshots2:**

[image]

Comment: i think reverse is happening. can you post screenshot of `system > Manage currency > Rates`

Comment: did you allowed US curency $ also under `system > general > currency set up` ?

Comment: can you add `0.015` under usd

Comment: but why as `INR` is 1.000 which is less than `USD`

Comment: your base currency is indian rupees, so you have to give 1.00 for indian rupees and according to base currency you have to give values for other currencies.

Comment: You got the solution?

Comment: I got it using below answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per screenshots you pasted, you gave wrong value under "USD" textfield. 
Give [0.015](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=itBWV5bzKcaL8Qfct5xY&gws_rd=ssl#q=1+indian+rupee+to+us+dollar) as value , once you gave correct value it will display proper value. you have to give the respective currency values with respect to the **Base currency = 1**.